# Persist a Map<Integer,Float> with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What's the best way to persist the following map in a class:

```
  @Entity
  class MyClass {


      @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)    
      Map<Integer,Float> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Float>(); 
  }
```

I've tried this, but the code results in:

**Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: mypackage.myClass.myMap[java.lang.Float]**

Comment: Why do you put a `@ManyToMany` annotation to your map? This annotation is to create relationship between entities (tables in DB speak)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `@ManyToMany` with `Integer` and `Float` because these types are value types, not entities. Use `@ElementCollection` (since Hibernate 3.5) or `@CollectionOfElements` (in previous versions).

```
@ElementCollection
Map<Integer,Float> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
```

**See also:**

- [7.2.3. Collections of basic types and embeddable objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-ofvalues)

Comment: Works wonderful, I see it doesn't import org.hibernate so it's part of JPA?

Comment: @Roalt: Yes, `@ElementCollection` is a part of JPA 2.0.

Comment: How do I override the names of the generated columns for the Map?

Comment: @SayoOladeji: use `@MapKeyColumn` for key and `@Column` for value